# If I have multiple if else statement like this how do you consider refactor it?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

If I have multiple if else statement like this how do you consider refactor it?

```
var a = DoSomethingToGetA();

if (UserPreviouslySignedIn)
{
    var b = DoSomethingToGetB();
  
    if (a == b && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
    {
        Validate(a);
    }
    else
    {
        Validate(b);
    }
}
else
{
    Validate(a);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd leave it like that in 90% of situations. Although, in practice your second `if` could be removed since it does nothing useful (i.e. `Validate(b);` can be done without the pointless comparison). And maybe move the `a` population into the final `else` since `a` isn't needed before that.

Comment: userPreviouslySignedIn && !StringUtils.equals(a, doSomethingToGetB()))? validate(doSomethingToGetB()): validate(a);    //I have inlined b and depending on your domain, I would encapsulate the conditional into a nicely named one liner function :)

Comment: If there is no StringUtils in your language / setup, then you can write it's implementation. It shouldn't be too much lines of code and would most probably be useful in other places as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could invert ifs and do early return to reduce nesting. Since you're doing the same call just with a different argument, you could also just determine the argument first and do a single call, something like this would do the same as your code I believe:

```
var a = DoSomethingToGetA();

if (!UserPreviouslySignedIn)
{
   Validate(a);
   return;
}

var b = DoSomethingToGetB();
var toValidate = (a == b && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)) ? a : b;

Validate(toValidate);
```

But if you're checking whether a == b before validating a, and otherwise b, it would just give you the same result if you always validated b. If it is equal to a, then you're just validating a, but named b, if they're not, you're validating b anyway.

So the only differing factor here would be the UserPreviouslySignedIn boolean. Which would mean it could be boiled down to a ternary assignment and single Validate call as such:

```
var toValidate = !UserPreviouslySignedIn ? DoSomethingToGetA() : DoSomethingToGetB();
Validate(toValidate);
```

Comment: That just seems more convoluted (to me), though it started well

Comment: There is a case where user had already previously signed in, then inside the webpage, they do a certain activivity that change the value of "a", and I have to validate by "a", not "b" anymore

Comment: Well then you'd probably need to have some invalidation that puts this UserPreviouslySignedIn back to false or something like that. Of course in that case I would recommend a different name for the variable.